# When using scroll Top, if footer disappears, add class to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When user scrolls to top and the footer hides, I detect it and add a class to it to make it visible by setting position fixed in CSS class. But when the footer is about to hide, the page blinks, the css class is added and removed in a few milliseconds. How to fix it so that the page doesn't blink? Thank you.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < ($(document).height() - $(selector).outerHeight())) {
    $(selector).addClass("stickybottom");;
}
else {
    $(selector).removeClass("stickybottom");
}
```

Comment: Is what you posted in a window scroll listener by chance? If so, most likely it's scrolling, going out of view, adding the class and then checking again and removing it because it goes from truthy to falsey in that amount of time based on what that CSS class does to the page. Need to see the listener. I'm guessing the footer gets set absolute and the page is at that second the same height again.

Comment: I think we need to see the HTML and the CSS.

Comment: Yes It's inside the window scroll, the full javascript is given on this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/yfs87jam/1. The HTML can be anything like footer or header. I'm basically making a free drupal module which people can use, so I can't know about the html.